# Rewrite URL after redirecting 404 error in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

How to redirect 404 , in htaccess I have add this

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/404/
ErrorDocument 500 http://example.com/500/
# or map them to one error document:
# ErrorDocument 404 /pages/errors/error_redirect.php
# ErrorDocument 500 /pages/errors/error_redirect.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/404/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/errors/404.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/500/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/errors/500.php [L]

# or map them to one error document:
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/404/$ [OR]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/500/$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/errors/error_redirect.php [L]
```

It has reduce but they are increasing, is there a way how can I redirect properly or maybe I'm mising something. How can I fix all of them ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to use RewriteRules. You can simply use an absolute path instead of using full url as your errordocument target :

```
ErrorDocument 404 /pages/errors/404.php
```